# How to compile a LigoLang jsLigo written smart contract on Windows + vsCode?

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, javascript, windows

I'm beginning to learn to write Tezos smart contracts with LigoLang using jsLigo as programming language and Windows as operating system. For IDE I'm using vsCode. I've followed the Getting Started tutorial on LigoLang website, but after everything had been setup I can't compile anything, getting an error.

Command:

```
   ligo compile contract starting.jsligo -m IncDec -o starting.tz
```

Result:

```
Uncaught exception:
  
  (Failure "Unknown algorithm 1.3.14.3.2.29")

Raised at Stdlib.failwith in file "stdlib.ml", line 29, characters 17-33
Called from Conduit_lwt_tls.X509.default_authenticator in file "src/conduit-lwt-unix/conduit_lwt_tls.real.ml", line 28, characters 26-38
```

I would like some guidance to go further in my studies. Can somebody help?

Comment: I've also configured vsCode settings with the path for Ligo binaries folder, with no different results.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I've just found the issue. Maybe this could help Windows users:

To compile on Windows you have to add ".exe" on the command, like this:

```
ligo.exe compile contract starting.jsligo -m IncDec -o starting.tz
```

This solves the problem.